# Asp.net System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException Error with ListBox SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, asp.net, tweetsharp

I get this error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.  Parameter name:index.

Same code was running perfectly in windows form app, but in asp.net i see this error.

My code is here:

```
public partial class Timeline : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        TwitterService servis;
        ListBox tweetid = new ListBox();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            servis = new TwitterService(consumer key,secret,token,token); 
            tweetid.Items.Clear();
            ListBox2.Items.Clear();
            IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> anasayfa = servis.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline(new ListTweetsOnHomeTimelineOptions { Count = 200 });
            var gelen = servis.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline(new ListTweetsOnHomeTimelineOptions { Count = 200, MaxId = anasayfa.Last().Id });
            foreach (var tweet in gelen)
            {
                    tweetid.Items.Add(tweet.Id.ToString());
                    ListBox2.Items.Add(tweet.Text);   
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            servis.Retweet(new RetweetOptions() { Id = long.Parse(tweetid.Items[ListBox2.SelectedIndex].ToString())});
            String uyarı = "alert('Retweetlendi!');";
            ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.GetType(), "ConfirmSubmit", uyarı);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its almost certainly `tweetid.Items[ListBox2.SelectedIndex]`. Validate the value of `SelectedIndex` before using it as an indexer.

Comment: To me it looks like tweetid may not be populated at the time of Button1_Click. Is the foreach loop inside of Page_Load?

Comment: @BrandonSpilove yes it's in page_load.

Comment: @StuartLC What should i do about that. like i said, this code was fine in windows form app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you have two `ListBoxes`, one (`tweetid`) storing the id's (presumably a key of sorts) of the tweets, and the other (`ListBox2`) storing the text of the tweets. You also don't seem to be adding the dynamically created `tweetid` ListBox to  the page anywhere (and presumably the intention is that the `tweetid ListBox` is hidden or similar).

You are then attempting to store synchronize the selected text drop down back to the original `tweetid` in the code behind Button click handler, based on the relative indexes of the data - it is apparant that the two listboxes are getting out of synch, plus, you aren't validating the user has selected a valid item, hence the `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception.

Although in theory this could be made to work, e.g. by ensuring that the data isn't lost in each page_load roundtrip as per @Dan's answer, and also by enabling `ViewState`, this all seems rather fragile to me.

I would propose that instead, you use a single `ListBox` and use the `DataTextField` to show the tweet to the user, and the `DataValueField` to track the Id of each tweet:

**.aspx**

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="TweetsListBox" DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Id" EnableViewState="True" />
```

**.aspx.cs Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Replace with your code to fetch tweets here
        TweetsListBox.DataSource = FetchSomeTweets();
        // We've alread set the names of the properties to use `Id` and `Text` in the aspx
        TweetsListBox.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    long tweetIdToRetweet;
    if (long.TryParse(TweetsListBox.SelectedValue, out tweetIdToRetweet))
    {
        servis.Retweet(new RetweetOptions() { Id = tweetIdToRetweet });
    }
    else
    {
        // Display Error that user must select a tweet
    }
}
```

For test purposes, I used the following mock models for your tweet service:

```
class Tweet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

private static readonly IEnumerable<Tweet> SomeTweets = new[]
{
    new Tweet { Id = 123, Text = "This is tweet 123" },
    new Tweet { Id = 234, Text = "This is tweet 234" },
    new Tweet { Id = 345, Text = "This is tweet 345" }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Stuart. that's really helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Your Page_Load method is populating the ListBox everytime the page postback, even before your button click event.

Thus, `ListBox2.SelectedIndex` will not be the the index that the user selected, since it is freshly populated in the Page_Load method.

You should add a postback check on your page_load and only populate the ListBox if the request is not a postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
        servis = new TwitterService(consumer key,secret,token,token); 
        tweetid.Items.Clear();
        ListBox2.Items.Clear();
        IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> anasayfa = servis.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline(new ListTweetsOnHomeTimelineOptions { Count = 200 });
        var gelen = servis.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline(new ListTweetsOnHomeTimelineOptions { Count = 200, MaxId = anasayfa.Last().Id });
        foreach (var tweet in gelen)
        {
                tweetid.Items.Add(tweet.Id.ToString());
                ListBox2.Items.Add(tweet.Text);   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? Which line of code are you getting the error on?

Comment: Same line; 'servis.Retweet(new RetweetOptions() { Id = long.Parse(tweetid.Items[ListBox2.SelectedIndex].ToString())});'